# Transfer learning + Selective Fine Tuning

Tags: keras, transfer-learning

This is a two part question:

**Background:**
I have a rather small set (thousands) of medical images. I am using pretrained models off of `kersa.applications` without their "top" layer and train my own top layer on top of them.
After I hit plateau performance / accuracy, I want to "fine tune" by making the pretrained model `trainable`

**Questions:**

1. Due to GPU memory limits (Tesla T4), I cannot mark the entire pretrained model with tens of millions of params trainable. Does it make sense to selectively choose layers or blocks / groups of layers and only make them trainable during fine tuning?
2. I have tried multiple approached to only make single layers (as opposed to the entire per-trained model) trainable but it looks like I am missing some trick, the number of trainable parameters I get out summary (after re-compiling) does not change.

Here is a selection of my code:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(last_saved_model_path)
model.summary()
# prints:
# layer 0 is input
# layer 1 is the pretrained model from keras.applications
# layers after that are my layers
# and shows x number of trainable params
model.layers[1].layers[-1].trainable = True
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
model.summary()
# shows the same number of trainable params
```

What am I missing, isn't it possible to make layers inside another layer trainable?